# can't install httpuv on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance (for Shiny)

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, ubuntu-20.04, httpuv

I'm following [the](http://www.kimberlycoffey.com/blog/2016/2/13/mlz90wjw0k76446xkg262prvjp0l8u) [many](https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/guide-shiny-aws/) [online](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-host-a-r-shiny-app-on-aws-cloud-in-7-simple-steps-5595e7885722) [tutorials](https://abndistro.com/post/2019/07/06/deploying-a-shiny-app-with-shiny-server-on-an-aws-ec2-instance/) [for](https://www.shafquatarefeen.com/aws-ec2-shiny-windows/) [setting up](https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-server-on-aws/) a Shiny server using AWS.  I created a free tier EC2 instance with Ubuntu 20.04 (64-bit), and I've installed R 3.6.3.

I can't install the `httpuv` package, which is a dependency of `shiny`.  (Other packages, such as `dplyr`, work just fine.)  [This gist](https://gist.github.com/kaplanas/f6c395c7f83349a611ccbdf35c90eed2) shows the output I see when I try to install `httpuv`; it's extremely long, and unfortunately the beginning of the output is cut off.  Before terminating, it sat at line 1205 for hours with no movement.

I'm not the first user to encounter this problem.  [This RStudio community post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-shiny-ubuntu-18-04-on-aws-t2-micro-httpuv-error/71231) from just a week ago looks like the same thing I'm experiencing.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727987/ubuntu-19-04-with-r-3-6-cant-install-r-shiny-package) has some suspiciously similar warning messages, but in that case the user solved the problem by re-installing R.  I have a brand-new R installation, so that solution doesn't help me.  One of the comments mentions encountering problems with limited memory on AWS and suggests installing from source; I get the same output.  I've also tried using a larger EC2 instance (30 GiB) and an older Ubuntu version (16.04); no difference.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2073) also involves `httpuv`, but the output seems to be different and the problem may have been specific to Raspberry Pi.  The first post in [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2054) mentions that it takes a long time to install `httpuv`, but installation didn't actually fail.

Comment: `g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus` - this is the important part. Looks like you're running out of memory during compilation. Can you use an EC2 instance with more memory? (Not disk space, which is what the 30 GiB refers to)

Comment: That did it; thank you!  It isn't possible to increase memory in the free tier (as far as I can tell), but I upgraded to `t2.medium` for long enough to install Shiny.  @greg L, if you want to post this comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @gregL thanks! Worked for me as well. It seems to be that shiny requires at least 2G of memory.

Comment: I think this is a problem of memory too